# How can I change the attributes of my class?

Tags: python, class, superclass

The class Athlete creates an object with the attributes; Name, TotalScore, Average, Deviation, Chance
I rename the the object to player. And when i read the lines i want the attributes in my class to change so it matches the information given in the file. I have read a little about superclasses but I don't know how to incorporate, is't right method to use in this case. I want the player object which is created to look like this:

```
player.Name = Donald Duck
player.TotalScore=0
player.Average = 18
player.Deviation = 2
player.Chance = 0.16
```

---

```
class Athlete(): 

    def __init_(self):
        self.Name=name
        self.TotalScore=0
        self.Average=0
        self.Deviation=0
        self.Chance=0.0


def PlayersFromFile(NameOfInputfile): 
    #define a list for player objects
    PlayerList =[]
    file = open(NameOfInputfile,'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        var1, var2, var3,var4 = line.split("\t")
        var4 = float(var4.rstrip())
        player = Athlete
        player.Name = var1
        player.Average = float(var2)
        player.Deviation = float(var3)
        player.Chance =var4
        playerList.append(player)
```

This how the file looks like:

```
Donald Duck 18  3   0.16
The Bear    17  4   0.25
Fair Brow   16  5   0.48
```

Comment: You don't want to rename the class, you want to create an instance of the class by *calling* it - ```player = Athlete()```.

Answer (score 1):

Som minor changes on the file might work

```
class Athlete():
    def __init_(self, name=None):
        self.Name=name
        self.TotalScore=0
        self.Average=0
        self.Deviation=0
        self.Chance=0.0


def PlayersFromFile(NameOfInputfile): 
    #define a list for player objects
    PlayerList =[]
    file = open(NameOfInputfile,'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        var1, var2, var3,var4 = line.split("\t")
        var4 = float(var4.rstrip())
        player = Athlete()
        player.Name = var1
        player.Average = float(var2)
        player.Deviation = float(var3)
        player.Chance =var4
        playerList.append(player)
```

note the name parameter in the Athlete class on the `__init__` function and the double parentheses in the Athlete call when the player instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever attribute which seems like it is  `self.Chancen` is not in the file you will have a default value:

```
class Athlete():
    def __init__(self,name, total_score=0, avg=0, dev=0, chnce=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.total_score = total_score
        self.average = avg
        self.deviation = dev
        self.chance = chnce

def players_from_file(input_file):
    player_list =[]
    with open(input_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            name, score, avg, dev = line.split("\t")
            dev = float(dev.rstrip())
            player_list.append(Athlete(name,float(score),float(avg), dev))
    return player_list
player = players_from_file("in.csv")
[<__main__.Athlete instance at 0x7f26194c5b00>, <__main__.Athlete instance at 0x7f26194c5ab8>, <__main__.Athlete instance at 0x7f26194c5bd8>]


for player in players:
    print(player.name,player.total_score)
('Donald Duck', 18.0)
('The Bear', 17.0)
('Fair Brow', 16.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining PlayerList inside your PlayersFromFile method, that means once the method has finished, it is inaccessible / deleted.

player is an instance of Athlete you are working on inside another Athlete instance, this is messy. And gives player a lot of methods to create new instances that it doesn't need.

Make 1 class that has the attributes a player need, then create a new instance of that for each player.

I am afraid I can not answer the question anymore than that and suggest you read up on namespace and classes on a basic level.

EDIT: Missed the wrong instantiation of the Athlete class, answer corrected.